# Psql format number so that it always has two decimal places

Tags: postgresql

If I have a number like this: `1205.5668` I know I can round to two decimal places by doing the following:

`select round(1205.5668,2);`

The above will return `1205.57` as expected.

How do I get two decimal places though if the number is already round? For example, I want `1200` to convert to `1200.00`

I've tried `select round(1200,2);` but it just displays `1200`

Comment: Try this `select round(cast(your_float_column as decimal(10,2)), 2, 1)
from your_table`

Comment: Try this `SELECT round( CAST(float8 '1200' as numeric), 2);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT round( CAST(float8 '1200.3363636' as numeric), 2);
SELECT round( CAST(float8 '1200' as numeric), 2);
```

[image]